# Saving longest list in Python

Tags: python, list, palindrome

I am correctly printing every palindromic substring of my input string. Then I return the final palindromic substring which is ["?"]. Makes perfect sense.

```
def longestPalindrome(s):
    longest = []
    palindrome = []
    for i in range(len(s)):
        for j in range(i, len(s)):
            palindrome.append(s[j])
            if palindrome == palindrome[::-1]:
                print(palindrome)
                longest = palindrome
        palindrome = []
    return longest

print(longestPalindrome("What kind of racecar do you drive?"))
```

I try to get only the longest palindrome by changing the if statement like this.

```
if palindrome == palindrome[::-1] and len(palindrome) > len(longest):
```

This is not working as expected. I'm only printing the first palindrome ["W"] then returning the entire string in a list ["W", "h", ...]

Comment: If you want a string instead of a list, though, you need to return one... `return ''.join(longest)`

Comment: I know how to return a string later that's not a problem.

Comment: I mean I included the exact input passed right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do `longest = palindrome`, you're pointing the reference of the `longest` list at `palindrome`, and therefore `palindrome.append(s[j])` is **also** appending to `longest`

You need to copy the list.

```
longest = palindrome[:]
```

For example,

```
def longestPalindrome(s):
    longest = []
    palindrome = []
    for i in range(len(s)):
        for j in range(i, len(s)):
            palindrome.append(s[j])
            if palindrome == palindrome[::-1] and len(palindrome) > len(longest):
                # print(palindrome, i, j)
                longest = palindrome[:]
        palindrome = []
    return ''.join(longest)

print(repr(longestPalindrome("What kind of racecar do you drive?")))
```

Your function should return `' racecar '` with your "fix" then.

Or you can simply use strings instead of lists.